# Fetch AWS lambda generated thumbnail in django template

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to make a gallery page in django where thumbnails of images are dislayed but by clicking it the full size image open. For this purpose, I have an Image model with a ImageField where the full size image is stored:

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):        
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery_images/')
```

When the file is uploaded to s3, it triggers a lambda function that create a thumbnail and save it in a subdirectory `gallery_images/thumbnails/`.

My question is how can I fetch the thumbnail to display it in the template? The exact location in s3 is known but I need to get a URL that, I think, contains a unique id for s3 to authenticate me.

Comment: Your application can create temporary pre-signed URLs for thumbnails in S3. You can use those as the img src in your HTML page.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for the hint it works perfectly. I just added a method to my model that returns the presigned url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the boto3 SDK, you can [create pre-signed URLs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url) for objects in S3.

For each thumbnail (or other private image) you want to show, generate a pre-signed URL and use it for the img src in your HTML page.

Note that pre-signed URLs have an expiration date/time so be sure it's long enough for your use case.